# Google Maps Android - How to call getMapAsync?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm following the guide from Google Dev [guides](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#add_map_code) on adding a map to an app. The only error (cannot resolve type) I'm getting now is with getMapAsync in my MainActivity.java class with this fragment.

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map); mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

According to the guide, I have to do this:

> Note: getMapAsync() must be called from the main thread, and the
>   callback will be executed in the main thread. If Google Play services
>   is not installed on the user's device, the callback will not be
>   triggered until the user installs Play services.

I have no idea on how to call getMapAsync from the main thread. Kinda new to this. Any help?

Comment: I have both of those imports. I added the override as well. Error with getMapAsync is still there.

Comment: Where did you put that code? It's meant to go inside "onCreate", after the line with "setContentView".

Comment: Thanks, flowtron. Turns out I added MapFragment after OnCreate instead of inside it. Changed the "}" to have it after MapFragment, and error leaves.

Answer (score 2):

```
package your.app.name;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                .title("Marker"));
    }

    //onCreateOptionsMenu: no changes    
    //onOptionsItemSelected: no changes
}
```

Of course, always assuming your activity_main.xml already contains proper fragment code and AndroidManifest.xml has the android.geo.API_KEY too.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `this` inside the `getMapAsync(this)` method. In your case `this` is the activity, while `getMapAsync` required the reference of the `MapFragment`. Pass the reference of the `MapFragment` which implements `OnMapReadyCallback`.